# Use a new line in the string

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am trying to use `&#13;` while creating a string with the new line.

Here is what I tried.

```
tooltip = "User is already present."+ &#13; + props.email;
```

But this is not working .while showing the tooltip.

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Add it inside the string directly.
```User is already present &#13; ```

Comment: No it does not work. I just tried

Comment: how is tooltip used?

Comment: Are you adding it in title attribute?

Comment: You can use \n(new line escape squence).

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, it needs to be done by using \n.

```
var foo = "Bob\nis\ncool.";

tooltip = "User is already present.\n"+ props.email;
```

Answer (score 1):

String templates allow to use new lines:

```
tooltip = `User is already present.
${props.email}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, you want to have the following text:

```
Hi!
I like JS
```

You can use `\n`:

`const myMessage = 'Hi!\nI like JS;'`

Or [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const myMessage = `Hi!
I like JS`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use

```
\n
```

in JavaScript code
and

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

in CSS to display new line

Comment: I think the css value is right, but the property is `white-space`. The full rule would be be `white-space: pre-line`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You're right. The correct css should be ```white-space: pre-line```. I don't know how to edit my post.

Comment: I think I was able to do it for you—it should show up in just a moment or two.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the html and get the html, like in below code you can remove first and last line and can use it as it is.

```
var props={email:'abc@gmail.com'}
var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
htmlObject.innerHTML = "User is already present. &#13;" + props.email;
tooltip = htmlObject.innerHTML ;
alert(tooltip);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use template literals in javascript it makes it more easier in all cases you do not need to add additional "\n" each time to add new line just right a paragraph with in quotes for help see this link it describe it very clearly

https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-template-literals/